# Преобразования типов JS

Tags: javascript, преобразование-типов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вычитание строкового значения влияет на значения двух переменных в данном примере? Спасибо!

```
var foo = '1';
var bar = '2';
var a = foo -= bar -= 'string';

// a = NaN - с этим понятно;
// foo = NaN - не понятно;
// bar = NaN - не понятно;
```

Comment: [Оператор немного не тот](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus), но суть та же: все пытается привестись к числу.

Comment: Да, понял, я упустил из внимания что там не просто '-', а '-=', спасибо! Для меня было непонятно почему меняются исходные переменные